# How do I solve this inequality with absolute value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$|8x-x^2|>x-18$$

Steps I took:

$$8x-x^{ 2 }>x-18\quad \quad \quad 8x-x^{ 2 }<18-x\quad $$

$$-x^{ 2 }+7x+18>0\quad \quad \quad -x^{ 2 }+9x-18<0\quad $$

$$x^{ 2 }-7x-18<0\quad \quad \quad x^{ 2 }-9x+18>0\quad $$

$$(x-9)(x+2)<0\quad \quad \quad (x-6)(x-3)>0\quad $$

How do I go from here?

No actual solution, please.

Comment: This is always true for $x \leq 18$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x < 18$ then the equation is automatically true, so you only need
consider $x \ge 18$.

In this case we have $x \ge 0$ and $8-x \le 0$, you can write the above as
$x (x-8) > x-18$, or
equivalently you need to figure out for what values of $x \ge 18$ is
$(x-3)(x-6) >0$?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit confused by the method you described. It even took me a minute to understand what you meant by how the equation is true when $x<18$. Since $|8x-x^{ 2 }|$ will always be greater than the right hand side if $x<18$. 

I'm not quite understanding the second portion of what you wrote.

Comment: Remember that $|8x-x^2| = |x| |8-x|$. First, if $x<18$ then the right hand side is negative and since the left hand side is always non negative and so all $x<18$ satisfy the inequality. Second, we now assume $x \ge 18$ and see which of these $x$ satisfy the inequality. Since $x \ge 18$, we have $x \ge 0$ and so $|x| = x$. Similarly $8-x <0$ and so $|8-x| = x-8$. So, since we assume that $x \ge 18$, we have $|8x-x^2| = x^2-8x$. Now we check for when $x^2-8x > x-18$. rearranging (and factoring)  gives $(x-3)(x-6) >0$. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) We see that if $x \ge 18$ then $x>3$ and $x>6$ and so the inequality is true. Hence the inequality is true for **all** $x$.

Comment: Your analytical approach to solving this problem is very elegant; however, I am having an issue when solving these type of problems. I know how to get to a certain point when solving them and then get stuck right around where I got stuck on this specific one. I just don't see how this analytical approach could be applied to a lot of other problems like this one.

Comment: There is no recipe, unfortunately, just a bag of tricks and keeping your eyes open.

Comment: Actually, what I said is not exactly true. The main issue is the $|\cdot|$. So you try to find ranges where the term inside $|\cdot|$ is negative or non negative and work from there. To some extent it is all about case analysis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You now have an expression for the explicit zeros. So, in between the two zeros on each side of the equation (as well as less than all the zeros and greater than all of the zeros), the function can only be positive or negative (since it doesn't cross the $x$-axis). Plug in test points and check whether it is positive or negative there. Can you follow through the rest?

Comment: Well if I just test each condition as you stated, I don't think it leads me to the correct solution. I seem to be getting that $x>6$ from the inequality I wrote on the right and $-2<x<9$ with the inequality on the left... This seems very off.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A general and standard way to solve this kind of equations proceeds with the steps:

1) find the intervals where the argument of the absolute value is positive or negative. In this case we have: 
$$
8x-x^2>0 \iff 0<x<8 \qquad \land \qquad 8x-x^2>0 \iff x<0 \lor x>8
$$

2) Now we can split the equation in two systems:

$$
\begin{cases}
0<x<8\\
8x-x^2>x-18
\end{cases} \quad
\lor \quad
\begin{cases}
x<0 \lor x>8\\
x^2-8x>x-18
\end{cases}
$$

3) solve the systems an take the union of the solution intervals.

Can you do this?